# How to pass table row id in POPUP

Tags: javascript

If i click the Addquestion button then popup open,that popup contains the relevant test id,how to pass relevant id popup.here i have attached image [1]

http://imageshack.com/a/img923/3150/6Hy4tp.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with jquery you can do this easily.I used an alert to show the id value,similarly you can pass this id value into your popup.Hope it helps

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#Approved",function(){
        var id = $(this).parent().siblings('.ids').text();
        
        alert(id);
       
    });
});
```

```css
#mytable tr td 
{
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" width="100%" style="border:1px solid;">
<thead  style="border:1px solid;">
<tr>
<th>Test ID</th>
<th>Test Name</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="test">
<td class="ids">11565-GHR </td>
<td class="testName">ASDSDSDSDSD</td>

<td><Button id="Approved" type="submit" >Add Question</button>
</td>

</tr>
<tr class="test">
<td class="ids">144545-ert </td>
<td class="tester">ASDSDSDSDSD</td>

<td><Button id="Approved" type="submit" >Add Question</button>
</td>

</tr>
<tr class="test">
<td class="ids">17878787-erer </td>
<td class="tester">ASDSDSDSDSD</td>

<td><Button id="Approved" type="submit" >Add Question</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Too kind. Should have waited for the question to be improved before answering. Nobody's gonna be able to find this answer.

Comment: but this is not working on my code,I have attached my code is above

Comment: did u add the jquery library in your code??? or add a fiddle of your code

Comment: add your code in jsfiddle and share the link  here .

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM test_preparation";
$result = $con->query($sql);echo "<table border='1'>
<tr><th style='text-align:center' >Test Id</th>
<th style='text-align:center'>Test name</th> 
<th colspan='3' style='text-align:center'>Action</th>
</tr>";while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['test_id'] . "</td>";
$_SESSION['testname']=$row['testname'];
$_SESSION['test-id']=$row['test_id'];
echo "<td>" . $row['program_name'] . '-'. $row['submodule_name'] ."</td>";echo "<td class='ids'>"
?><button type="submit" id="Approved">Add question</button>

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#Approved",function(){
        var id = $(this).parent().siblings('.ids').text();
        
        alert(id);
       
    });
});
</script>

Comment: I think you didnt add the class ids in the right row  look  <td>" . $row['test_id'] . "</td>" here may be you are binding your test id  but in this <td> you didn't added the "ids" class may be thats why its not working correctly

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Elakiyasiva/v4kdgotw/
Here i have not  mention the db details